# jQuery Sortable issue on Note/ Tab

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am working on jQuery sortable. Which working fine with Desktop but whatever result I am getting from the desktop expected the same on Samsung Galaxy Note 800 Device.

I have li list of Blue Color.
On over it showing Green. [While dragging / sorting it should be green].
After dropping / mouseout it showing brown.

Which is working perfect on the desktop but in the above said device the draggable / sortabble div's place taking by a div which still shows Green color which should be blue.[image]

How to remove that green from the device?

CSS:

```
#sortable { list-style-type: none; margin: 0; padding: 0; width: 60%; border:1px solid red;}
#sortable li { margin: 0 3px 3px 3px; padding: 0.4em; padding-left: 1.5em; font-size: 1.4em; height: 18px; background-color:blue; border:1px solid green; color:white;}
#sortable li span { position: absolute; margin-left: -1.3em;  border:1px solid pink;}
#sortable li:hover{
    background-color:green;
}
.ui-state-default.ui-sortable-helper{
    background-color:yellow;
}
.ui-sortable-placeholder{
background-color:yellow;
}
.dragging{
    background-color:pink;
}
.dropped{
    background-color: brown !important;
}
.dropped:hover{
    background-color: green !important;
}
```

HTML:

```
<ul id="sortable">
    <li class="ui-state-default"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-arrowthick-2-n-s">1</span>Item 1</li>
    <li class="ui-state-default"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-arrowthick-2-n-s">2</span>Item 2</li>
    <li class="ui-state-default"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-arrowthick-2-n-s">3</span>Item 3</li>
    <li class="ui-state-default"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-arrowthick-2-n-s">4</span>Item 4</li>
    <li class="ui-state-default"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-arrowthick-2-n-s">5</span>Item 5</li>
    <li class="ui-state-default"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-arrowthick-2-n-s">6</span>Item 6</li>
    <li class="ui-state-default"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-arrowthick-2-n-s">7</span>Item 7</li>
</ul>
```

jQuery:

```
$(function() {
$( "#sortable" ).sortable({
start: function (event, ui) {
ui.item.addClass("dragging");
},
stop: function (event, ui) {
setTimeout(function(){
ui.item.addClass("dropped");
$(document).focus();
},500);

//EnableDisableContentPlayerButtons(false, false, false);
}
});
//$( "#sortable" ).disableSelection();
});
```

`

Answer (score 0):

Its probably due to mouse events not fully recognized on tablet.

you could use Touch Punch http://touchpunch.furf.com/

all you have to do is include it and it will extend Jquery UI with touch events.

```
<script src="jquery.ui.touch-punch.min.js"></script>
```

hope this helps!